# How can I work out if site has broken inheritance or not already using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I'm needing to do all my commands using the SharePoint REST API. Is there a property somewhere in the REST API calls that tells me if the site has broken inheritance or not?

Answer (score 3):

So I found the answer. The property is one that doesn't seemed to be documented and it doesn't come back in the normal property values. You have to specifically ask for it.

E.g, Looking for unique permission on a Web.

```
<site>/_api/web
```

The above results will not tell you if the web site has unique permissions.

```
<site>/_api/web?$select=hasuniqueroleassignments
```

The above REST call will bring back a property with a Boolean value.